# How to insert an item in a list where the current user hasn't permission

Tags: permissions

I have a web part that, after insert an item in a list where the current user has the permission, need to insert an item in a list where the current user hasn't access.
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe Gaetanu You Are doing something wrong? Try to sit in it more then 25 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method to elevate your code and allow the user permission to the list.

```
SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
     // code to run here
   item["Editor"] = currentUser;
   item["Author"] = currentUser;
   item.Update();
});
```

HTH

Comment: I read that is not a good way to accomplish this issue and I after the update I haven't the item in the list

Comment: I'm curious, where did you read this is not a good method to use? Run a debugger and ensure the code is firing. It should work without issue. On your new items, if you want them tagged from the current user, you need to declare a user object outside of the method, then set it to the Author and Editor fields.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36301/in-which-situation-use-spsecurity-runwithelevatedprivileges-with-superusertoken

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, I haven't come across that before. Asking my colleagues at the table, they also lean towards using SPSecurity.RunwithElevatedPrivilege. I'm going to do some more research to see what the real differences are.